# Edit changeset comments - save disabled

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2013

I need to find my recent changesets so I can add something to each one.

I tried doing a View History in source control explorer, but I don't see a way to filter that by user. (If I use this approach, I can open a changeset and successfully change the comment. However, this is a pain because it's not filtered by user.)

I also tried right-clicking on a team project and doing Find -> Find changesets. That brings up a dialog where I can find changesets just for me. However, the save button is disabled? Why?

[image]

How can I get the save button enabled? Or, if that can't happen, how can I find just my changesets and add some data to each comment?

Comment: I have the same issue. It seems to be a bug, because when you open the changeset through the history, it can be edited and saved. Did you get any other info about it?

Comment: I did not. I gave up.

Comment: @natenho Vote here: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedbackdetail/view/921820/changeset-detail-window-save-button-always-disabled

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I see this in Visual Studio 2012, not sure about 2013.  The Save button is disabled, but I know a workaround - if I type in the Comment area by adding a space and then removing it (from anywhere), then select a file below to take focus off the Comment box, then go back to type in the Comment area again, it is enabled.  Visual Studio bug.

Comment: This didn't work exactly as you described with VS 2013. However by going to the Check-in Notes tab and altering the Code Reviewer text box, that caused the Save button to be enabled.

Answer (score 4):

This is Visual Studio bug. Workaround is even simpler than suggested above. Type at the end of comment [Space], [Backspace], [Space] and Save button is enabled.

Comment: THIS ACTUALLY WORKED! Lmao...and VS is just celebrating 20 years this year but still has simple bugs like this.

Answer (score 3):

1. To use the changeset command you must have the Read permission set to Allow for any files or folders in the changeset for which you wish to display full information. **The only users who can modify the notes and comments that are associated with a changeset are the users who created the changeset or a user who has the Revise other user's changes global permission.**
2. Check in - **Users who have this permission can check in items and revise any committed changeset comments. Pending changes are committed at check-in.**

As per 1 & 2 you should be able to edit your changeset comments without any special permissions, I verified this in our TFS server. I am able to edit and save the comments (since am an admin I can revise others changes too). I also locked (took out check-in permissions for my ID) for an entire branch and then tried to edit my changeset comments and it worked too. I use VS 2010 and TFS 2010.

**Update**: Check if you have the "Edit project-level information" set to allow. I noticed that when I remove this access my "save" button also gets disabled when I go through the Find -> Find changeset route. You can get there by VS -> Team -> Team project Settings -> Security

[image]

Source Link: [LINK1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w51xa47k%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
Source Link: [LINK2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252587%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for that info. So you're basically confirming that I shouldn't have this issue. But I do. The problem is why?

Comment: Thanks! I can try that tomorrow morning and let you know.

Comment: +1 for the tip, but the button is still disabled. I think you have the right idea though; it must be another setting in there somewhere.

Comment: Do you have both Edit project-level and view project-level info set to allow?

Comment: Same issue, it seems to become enabled randomly.  I have exited and gone back into the changeset several times.